# Warning when run tf contrib learn linear regression example

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code raised some warnings posted after the code. What is wrong with it and how to fix them.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('x', dimension=1)]

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)

x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
 
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
 
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
    {'x':x_train}, y_train,
    batch_size=4, 
    num_epochs=1000) 

eval_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
    {'x':x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

train_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)
eval_loss = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print('train loss: %r'% train_loss)
print('eval loss: %r'% eval_loss)
```

=======================================================================

WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprlxunsfy`

`WARNING:tensorflow: Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for a column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.`

WARNING:tensorflow:From `C:\python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.`

Instructions for updating:

Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.

WARNING:tensorflow: Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for a column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.

WARNING:tensorflow:From `C:\python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.`

Instructions for updating:

Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.

`WARNING:tensorflow: Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.`

`WARNING:tensorflow: Rank of input Tensor (1) should be the same as output_rank (2) for a column. Will attempt to expand dims. It is highly recommended that you resize your input, as this behavior may change.`

WARNING:tensorflow:From `C:\python\Python352\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\estimators\head.py:615: scalar_summary (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-11-30.`

Instructions for updating:

Please switch to tf.summary.scalar. Note that tf.summary.scalar uses the node name instead of the tag. This means that TensorFlow will automatically de-duplicate summary names based on the scope they are created in. Also, passing a tensor or list of tags to a scalar summary op is no longer supported.

`WARNING:tensorflow: Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.`

> train loss: {'loss': 6.2396435e-09, 'global_step': 1000}
>
> eval loss: {'loss': 0.0025317217, 'global_step': 1000}

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, pass model_dir= explicitly to LinearRegressor **init**.  That way you know where it is.

Not sure what the input-output rank warning is.  But all others are internal to the Estimator, and therefore you don't have to worry about and can't fix.